# FTP response codes

Tags: iis-6, ftp

I am troubleshooting Microsoft's FTP server (IIS 6.0) at a client site.  In the FTP log, there's a few response codes that I'd like to know the meaning of.

For instance, in the line:

12:01:15 10.4.152.122 [194326]created x.jpg 550 1450

I'd like to know the meaning of 1450. There's other ones as well, like 550 2, and 550 32.

Anyone know of a site or reference that has the meaning of these sub-codes (not sure what the correct term is)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 450 / 550 values are both from [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959).

As 450 and 550 are both FTP errors, the second values *might* correspond to Windows error codes.  The page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381.aspx) is consistent with that, with values 2, 32, and 1450 all relating to file I/O errors.

> 2 = `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`
>
> - The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> 32 = `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`
>
> - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.
>
> 1450 = `ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES`
> - Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested
> service.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.altools.com/image/support/alftp/ALFTP_35_help/FTP_response_codes_rfc_959_messages.htm), 550 is:

```
Requested action not taken.
File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
```